# Why does lapply with closures give errors?

Tags: r, closures, lapply

[R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#subsection.8.3.16) gives explaining the following output as a challenge:

```
>xr <- lapply(11:14,function(i) function() i^2)
>sapply(1:4, function(j) xr[[j]]())
[1]196 196 196 196
```

and I'm ashamed to say that I've failed it. What's going on? My guess is that it's something to do with `i^2` remembering the environment that it was defined in, but I'm pretty sure that each element of `xr` used a different `i`, which also rules out thing being a lazy evaluation problem.

Comment: Is not better to use `lapply(11:14,function(i) i^2)`?

Comment: @Duck The code is deliberately bad for the sake of the challenge.

Comment: Using your code I got `121 144 169 196`

Comment: @Duck That's strange. I'm sure that I copied their code faithfully.

Comment: You will get `i` from their environment with `environment(xr[[1]])$i`

Comment: @J.Mini Maybe re start `R` and try over a new fresh session.

Comment: @Duck The R Inferno is old. Lazy evaluation within `lapply` worked differently in old versions of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine that you create the following functions:

```
xr1 <- function() 11^ 2
xr2 <- function() 12 ^ 2
xr3 <- function() 13 ^ 2
xr4 <- function() 14 ^ 2
```

So when you call any one of them you get

```
xr1()
#[1] 121

xr3()
#[1] 169
```

Now instead of doing the same function 4 times for different numbers, we loop over the values we want to raise to power of 2 and create a list with 4 functions as its elements, i.e.

```
xr <- lapply(11:14, function(i) function() i ^ 2)
```

So now `xr` is a list with 4 functions.

Function 1 , i.e. `xr[[1]]()` will give 11^2 = 121

Function 2, i.e. `xr[[2]]()` will give 12^2 = 144
and so on...

So instead of calling each one separately, we now use `sapply` to loop over each element of `xr` and evaluate its function, hence

```
sapply(1:4, function(j) xr[[j]]())
#[1] 121 144 169 196
```